# Populate a Text Box based on a Combo and Text Box Input

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have one Combo Field and one Text Box Field in my Access DB's Form.
I would like to have my 2nd Text Box Field to get the data from a Table based on the Combo and Text Box Field Data.

Is it possible? or auto-fill in the Access text box only can base on a combo box?

Example:-
The combo field was selected from table-1 consists of the equipID_PK and equipDesc.

The 1st Text box contains the data obtained from the table-2 Block, Floor, and Room. When Block was selected, the floor and room (1st Text Box) will auto-filled.

Based on the combo field (equipDesc) and 1st Text Box data (Room Field), I want the 2nd Text Box to fillup a subEquipDesc which is from Table-3.

I need help on how to set up this Table-3. Some of the Equipment (EquipDesc-in Table-1), when placed in a different room, will have a different description (different software loaded), I called it SubEquipDesc.

Hope is clear and let me know if more explanation is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the extra field to your combo box, increase the column count, and set the column width to be 0 (so that it isn't shown to the user), you can then set the `ControlSource` of the text box to show this hidden column:

```
=[Combo0].[column](2)
```

Note that columns in a combo box are 0-indexed, so the example above shows the third column of data.

Regards,

Comment: I am sorry, I have missed out to mention that the 2nd Text Box field was taken from another Table and not the same Table as the Combo and 1st Text Box field.

Comment: Please modify your question to include details about the two tables, including how the information from the second table is to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are describing a "junction" table. Your table set-up should be something like:

- tblEquipment - EquipID (Primary key), EquipDesc;
- tblRoom - RoomID (Primary key), Block, Floor, Room;
- tblRoomEquip - RoomEquipID (Primary key), EquipID (Foreign key from tblEquipment), RoomID (Foreign key from tblRoom).

In the form that is based on tblRoomEquip, you should be using combo boxes to select the information for Equipment and Room, based on the respective tables. Using a text box is not recommended when you have the information already stored in a table.

Regards,

Comment: I will make changes to my tables and text boxes to combo boxes. With the changes, how can I auto-fill the sub equipment from tblRoomEquip if I add the sub equipment desc into table 3?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You should have a form based on the junction table with combo boxes based on the other two tables that are bound to the relevant fields.